# Unicoins Lite Coin payments problem

Tags: support, bug, unicoins, april-fools

I am keep getting error while trying to purchase unicoins with Lite Coin.

I been mining for an hour, but my hand is in pain. All I want is to put all your heads in to bubble. It cost 75 unicoins.

[image]

Comment: status-bydesign is my guess since none of them work

Comment: Pay me and I'll send you whatever number of coins you need

Comment: @Mr.Alien Excellent idea! Do you except Reddit reputation?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Nah, I accept only Stack Rep ;)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately due to the unprecedented demand for unicoins the exchange rate is currently

`1 unicoin = ∞ All other currencies`

As you do not currently have ∞ Lite Coin your purchase cannot be completed

Comment: There is a problem with your answer. Your 8 drop dead.